# Check whether a file uses CRLF or LF to end lines

Tags: text, newlines

How to check whether lines in a text file end with CRLF or LF?

Comment: Type `file <filename>`. If it makes no mention, it's LF; if it's CRLF, it'll say "with CRLF line terminators".

Comment: Are you asking how to detect which line endings are used in a file?  Or are you asking how to process a file which contains both `LF` and `CRLF` line endings?  Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 7):

As Tom Hunt said, you can use `file` and it will tell you if the lines end with CRLF.

Or you can use GNU `cat -A filename` to visually inspect the file.  Lines ending in CRLF will look like:

```
blahblahblah^M$
```

A more portable alternative is to use `sed -n l filename`.  Lines ending with CRLF will look like:

```
blahblahblah\r$
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about the cat or sed ways, but I use this:

```
tr "\r" "@" < $FILE | grep --color "@$"
```

which replaces the CR with a @ (vim's ":set list" style) and shows the resulting @'s at the end of each line in color.